# PDFBox field value cannot display after flatten

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a PDF form which is created by LiberOffice Draw 4.1.0.4.

The form contains text field, check box and radio button

After I set value to the fields and flatten the form with PDFBox(2.0.21), the field value cannot be displayed

I think it may be the problem of the appearance of the field's annotation but I have no idea how to make it right

[Test PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VPIMe3UltcDcmHDpyVs_2eMtXDkiSHhU/view?usp=sharing)

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField;

import java.io.File;

public class PdfGenerationTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{
        testFillValue();
    }
    
    public static void testFillValue() throws Exception{
        PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\temp\\test.pdf"));
        
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        
        String defaultAppearance = "/Helv 12 Tf 0 0 1 rg";
        
        for(PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
            if (field instanceof PDTextField) {
                PDTextField textField = (PDTextField) field;
                textField.setActions(null);             
                textField.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearance);
            }
        }
        
        setFormValue(acroForm, "TextBox", "testvalue");
        setFormValue(acroForm, "radioBtn", "Yes");
        setFormValue(acroForm, "chkBox", "Yes");
        acroForm.refreshAppearances();
        acroForm.flatten();
        
        pdDocument.save("C:\\temp\\test_filled.pdf");
        pdDocument.close();
    }
    
    private static void setFormValue(PDAcroForm acroForm, String key, String value) throws Exception {
        PDField f = acroForm.getField(key);        
        if (f != null) {
            if (value != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value.trim())) {
                f.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please retry with 2.0.24

Comment: Works as expected with head version; an update indeed should suffice.

Comment: Retried with 2.0.24 and succeed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PDAcroForm.flaten is work for me after using pdfbox 2.0.24

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-examples</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I doubt you need pdfbox-examples.